# Why does qsort only sorts a maximum of 8 elements

Tags: c, pointers, std, quicksort, qsort

I was writing a code which is using qsort from <stdlib.h>. While my Code is absolutly working fine for 8 elements in of the Array that will be sorted it doesnt for more then 10 elements. I`ve no idea why it doesnt work, I hope you can help me out.

Talking about the Problem:
I was trying to sort a float Array with 10 Elements. On the fact this didnt work I tried to make it easier by using only Integers. While i was tesing it I realised that qsort works pretty good by using 8 elements or less for the array. When i was using more then 8 elements it wasnt working at all. Some elements (always the same ones) were sorted others werent. at all they werent listed correct. So I tried other codes to solve the problem but not a single code changed something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int CompareFloat(const void* pcv1, const void* pcv2);
int CompareIntegers(const void* pcv1, const void* pcv2);

int main()
{
    int aiArr[10] = { 10,9,8,7,5,6,4,2,3,1};
    int aiArr2[8] = { 8,7,6,5,4,2,3,1 };
    float afArr[8] = { 5.0f, 4.611f, 4.61f, 4.1f, 4.0f, 10.0f, 1.9f, 1.8f };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", afArr[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t", aiArr[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t", aiArr2[i]);
    }

    qsort(aiArr2, 8, sizeof(int), CompareIntegers);
    qsort(aiArr, 10, sizeof(int), CompareIntegers);
    qsort(afArr, 8, sizeof(float), CompareFloat);
    puts("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", afArr[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t", aiArr[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t", aiArr2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int CompareFloat(const void* pcv1, const void* pcv2)
{
    int iRet;

    float* pf1 = (float*)pcv1;
    float* pf2 = (float*)pcv2;

    if (*pf1 < *pf2)
    {
        iRet = -1;
    }
    if (*pf1 > *pf2)
    {
        iRet = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        iRet = 0;
    }

    return iRet;
}
int CompareIntegers(const void* pcv1, const void* pcv2)
{
    int iRet;
    int* pi1 = (int*)pcv1;
    int* pi2 = (int*)pcv2;

    if (*pi1 < *pi2)
    {
        iRet = -1;
    }
    if (*pi1 > *pi2)
    {
        iRet = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        iRet = 0;
    }

    return iRet;

}
```

Output (cutt some 0):

```
1.8000  1.9000  4.0000  4.1000  4.6100  4.6110  5.0000       10.0000

1     3     2     4     5     6     7     8     9       10

1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Expected Output (cut some 0):

```
1.8000  1.9000  4.0000  4.1000  4.6100  4.6110  5.0000  10.0000 

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

I was reading a lot of code and more informations about qsort but its not working fine. The elemts of the bigger array arent sorted, like they should (I think so).

Comment: [Works on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3PT157nja)

Comment: Please [edit] and show your verbatim actual output vs. your expected output as properly formatted text.

Comment: There's some logic errors in your comparison functions. If the first argument is less than the second, your code actually says they're equal.

Comment: @Shawn the comparision functions look OK to me. Could you explain what's specifically wrong in the OP's functions?

Comment: Because the second comparison lacks `else`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The first `if` is pointless; the next `if`/`else` will always overwrite the value it sets.

Comment: @Shawn you're right, but the question deserves a proper answer and should not have been closed.

Comment: @Shawn it took a moment but now I think I see  the problem. the seconf if/else always writes 1 or 0... Thank you!

Comment: @Jabberwocky: StackOverflow is not a site for debugging every program, especially ones with trivial bugs. Proper use of `if… else if… else` needs to be taught in C courses, and keeping a repository filled with samples of elementary errors is not much help to students, as there is no way to search by the nature of the error (somebody else with a broken `if` chain is not going to search for questions entitled “qsort only sorts a maximum of 8 elements”).

Comment: The 'single return' philosophy is part of the trouble.  If the code used `if (*pi1 < *pi2) return -1; if (*pi1 > *pi2) return +1; return 0;`, then there's no need for `else` (though it wouldn't be wrong).  I'd also capture the integers once: `int i1 = *(const int *)pcv1; int i2 = *(const int *)pcv2;` and then use direct integer comparisons.  The optimizer probably does this anyway.  Only keep the pointers if you're dealing with structures rather than scalar values.

Comment: doubleSpace, Idiomatic: `return (*pf1 > *pf2) - (*pf1 < *pf2)`.  Many compilers recognize this and emit optimal  code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your compare functions, you left off `else` in your second `if`.

You have:

```
    if (*pi1 < *pi2)
        iRet = -1;
    if (*pi1 > *pi2)
        iRet = 1;
    else
        iRet = 0;
```

Consider what happens when `*pi1 < *pi2`.  The first `if` is true, so we set `iRet = -1`.  We then go on to the second `if` (this is the bug).  The second `if` is false, so we set `iRet = 0`.  Thus we end up returning 0 instead of the correct result -1.

A three-way test should instead look like:

```
    if (*pi1 < *pi2)
        iRet = -1;
    else if (*pi1 > *pi2) // note else here
        iRet = 1;
    else
        iRet = 0;
```

so that only one of the branches ever executes.

Alternatively, use an "early return":

```
   if (*p1 < *p2)
      return -1;
   if (*p1 > *p2)
      return 1;
   return 0;
```

Comment: Or even: `int CompareIntegers(const void *pcv1, const void *pcv2) { int i1 = *(const int *)pcv1; int i2 = *(const int *)pcv2; return (i1 > i2) - (i1 < i2); }` which has a variety of helpful changes but mostly is a lot shorter than the original.  Using `if (i1 > i2) return +1; if (i1 < i2) return -1; return 0;` also works neatly.  The compiler probably optimizes to only evaluate `*p1` and `*p2` once each.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think yours actually optimizes worse.  Either of the original versions compiles into one conditional set and one conditional move.  Yours compiles into two conditional sets and a subtract.  https://godbolt.org/z/9qMn53hq3  All of them optimize out the extra loads of `*p1` and `*p2`, that's pretty basic CSE.  Yours certainly is shorter, I think it's debatable whether it's more readable.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading, I'll just add the usual caution against the apparently clever `return *p1 - *p2;` which looks nice on paper, but can overflow and cause undefined behavior.